# Using InStr function to count how many words contain ALL specific letters of a unique word

Tags: excel, vba

Need to create a macro that would count ALL words in a large data set, that contain ALL letters of a specific word. It can contain letters that my word does not have but MUST contain at least all letters my word has. For example, if unique word is "Orchids", the word doctorship would count.

Edit: All data is located to row 252679 in column A

I'm trying to see if I am on the right track, I am also not sure if my code excludes from counting duplicate letters.

So far I've come up:

```
Dim count As Long
Dim word As String
Dim row As Long

count = 0

    For row = 2 To 252679
        word = Cells(row, 1).Value
        
    If InStr(1, word, "a", vbTextCompare) Then
    If InStr(1, word, "c", vbTextCompare) Then
    If InStr(1, word, "a", vbTextCompare) Then
    If InStr(1, word, "d", vbTextCompare) Then
    If InStr(1, word, "e", vbTextCompare) Then
    If InStr(1, word, "m", vbTextCompare) Then
    If InStr(1, word, "y", vbTextCompare) Then
        count = count + 1
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
Next row
MsgBox "CountWordsMatchingALL = " & count
```

Comment: Please clarify what is your question, you only stated your requirements but not your issue.

Comment: I don't see a question here at all. What problem are you having with the code you posted, and what **specific question** do you have related to that code?

Comment: I'm trying to see if I'm on the right track. I'm also not sure if my code includes duplicates or not since in "academy" the letter "a" appears twice.

Comment: I would say you have elements of the right track. One typical way of handling this problem would be to create two nested loops. The outer loop for letters of the 1st word, thebinner loop for the 2nd word. Pull individual letters from arrays and compare them. When they match, add 1 to a counter variable. Be aware that arrays are 0 indexed by default, so the 1st element (letter, in your case) would be `ary(0)`, and 2nd letter would be stored in `ary(1)`, etc. Use `SPLIT()` to populate your arrays with their words.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Debug.Print HasAllLetters("Dog", "done")
    
    Debug.Print HasAllLetters("Cat", "Scatter")

End Sub


'return true if all letters in `myWord` are present in `testWord`
Function HasAllLetters(ByVal myWord As String, ByVal testWord As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    'converting to lower case is faster than using `vbTextCompare`
    testWord = LCase(testWord) 'case-insensitive
    myWord = LCase(myWord)
    For i = 1 To Len(myWord)
        If Not InStr(testWord, Mid(myWord, i, 1)) > 0 Then Exit Function
    Next i
    HasAllLetters = True
End Function
```

Comment: @RaymondWu- yes that's better than my approach - fixed above.

Answer (score 0):

### Count Cells Containing All Characters of a String

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CallCountCellsHaveAllChars()
    
    Dim AllCharsCount As Long
    AllCharsCount = CountCellsHaveAllChars(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"), "orchids")
    
    MsgBox "Count of Cells Matching All Characters: " & AllCharsCount
 
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In a one-column range, counts the number of cells whose
'               values (strings) contain all characters of a string ('Word').
' Calls:        'RefColumn','GetColumnRange','HasAllChars'.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function CountCellsHaveAllChars( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range, _
    ByVal Word As String) _
As Long
    
    ' Create a reference to the one-column range ('crg').
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = RefColumn(FirstCell)
    If crg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    ' Write the values of the range to a 2D one-based one-column array ('Data').
    Dim cData As Variant: cData = GetColumnRange(crg)
    
    ' Loop through the array and count the matches.
    Dim r As Long
    Dim Sentence As String
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(cData, 1)
        Sentence = CStr(cData(r, 1))
        If HasAllChars(Sentence, Word) Then
            CountCellsHaveAllChars = CountCellsHaveAllChars + 1
        End If
    Next r

End Function
    
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range from the first cell
'               of a range ('FirstCell') to the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.count - .row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.row - .row + 1)
    End With

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values from a column ('ColumnNumber')
'               of a range ('rg') to a 2D one-based one-column array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetColumnRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnNumber As Long = 1) _
As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If ColumnNumber < 1 Then Exit Function
    If ColumnNumber > rg.Columns.count Then Exit Function
    
    With rg.Columns(ColumnNumber)
        If rg.Rows.count = 1 Then
            Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
            GetColumnRange = Data
        Else
            GetColumnRange = .Value
        End If
    End With

End Function
    
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether a string ('Sentence')
'               contains all characters of another string ('Word').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function HasAllChars( _
    ByVal Sentence As String, _
    ByVal Word As String) _
As Boolean
    
    Dim w As Long
    
    For w = 1 To Len(Word)
        If InStr(1, Sentence, Mid(Word, w, 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next w
    
    HasAllChars = True
    
End Function
```